# Printer driver needs to be installed on every reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer, network-printer

Currently I have a Dell 1815n MFP printer to which is connected to my network via ethernet and a router to which the rest of my computers are attached to as well.  I can install the printer fine by using the Windows tool to add a new printer, windows finds it automatically in the list, and then selecting the driver which I have saved on my C drive.  The installation goes through, perfectly fine and I can print no problem.

When I reboot however if I try to select the printer it is greyed out and the print job just stays in queue, never actually printing. If I update the driver to the same one, in the same location, it asks if I want to replace the current driver or update to the new one, which both result in the same driver and it works fine again. Any ideas?

Comment: I like to add the printer as local, then add the port separately. If the printer port is set to the printer's IP address, try setting it to the printer's network name/node name instead. (e.g. instead of "192.168.1.10" try "//NP23456") You can usually find/set this name via the printer's web page or by printing it's network config via it's menus.

Comment: And/or assign a static IP to the printer, or reserve an IP in the DHCP servers MAC table.